# How to render something first in shiny before excuting the rest of code?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to render a text to notify the user that a task is going to run, but it seems that shiny executes all code in server first then it moves to UI. 
Here is an example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
         textOutput("ptext")
      ))

server <- function(input, output) {
   output$ptext <- renderText("creating a dataframe")
   df <- matrix(rnorm(10000),nrow = 10) # a large dataset
   output$ptext <- renderText("dataframe created !!")
   }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In the above example, I never see "creating a dataframe", How to render that text first before executing the rest of the code.

Comment: Using [Shiny Progress](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/Progress.html) is no option?

Comment: That is so nice :)) It worked well for my problem. I would also be happy if I found a way to prioritize render tasks before the rest of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the most beautiful, but if you can use an *input* for status messages like this, you can relay what's going on ...

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    textInput("notice", "Status", "creating a dataframe"),
    textOutput("ptext")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dat <- reactive({
    Sys.sleep(3)
    matrix(rnorm(10000), nrow = 10)
  })

  output$ptext <- renderText({
    req(dat())
    updateTextInput(session, "notice", value = "dataframe created !!")
    return("hello world")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

(Note the addition of `session` to the arguments to `server`, necessary to use `updateTextInput(session, ...)`.)

You could get more complex by using dynamic UI creation and deletion, or object hiding (perhaps using [`shinyjs`](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs)), but that is getting a bit more complex than I think you may want.

Comment: Elmahy, does this give you any capability in your need to alter dependency priorities?